# ¿Cómo funciona este programa en C?

Tags: c, depuración

Estoy realizando un programa en *Python* para controlar un generador de funciones, modelo **DS345**. Todo muy bien, hasta que llegué a la función arbitraria, donde tengo que enviar una lista de puntos y un *checksum* (suma de verificación).

La teoría me dice que tengo que enviar un código `LDWF0,#puntos` a enviar, esperar una respuesta del generador de funciones con un `1`, y proceder a enviar los puntos y el checksum. Quiero entender paso a paso qué es lo que realiza un ejemplo en *C*.

```
/* program to donwload point mode arb wf to DS345.The waveform is a simple ramp.
    Written in Microsoft C and uses National Instrument GPIB card. Expects DS345
    to be installed as DS345 in IBCONF
*/

void main(void);

int ds345;

int data[10000]; /* up to 10000 points */

void main ()
{

    char cmd[40];

    int i,sum,j,number;

    if ((ds345 = ibfind("DS345")) < 0) /* open National driver */
    {
        printf ("Cannot find DS345\n"); exit(1);
    }

    sum = 0; /* initialize checksum */

    j = -2048; /* initial ramp value (-full scale)*/

    number = 8192; /* number of points in waveform */

    /* will make a 8192 point ramp, increment y value every other point */

    for (i = 0 ; i < number ; i++)
    {
        data[i] = j; /* y value */

        sum += data[i]; /* add to checksum */

        if (i&1)j++; /* increment y value if i is odd */
    }

    data[number] = sum; /* checksum */

    sprintf (cmd,"LDWF?0,%d\n",number); /* command to load waveform */

    ibwrt (ds345,cmd,strlen(cmd));

    ibrd (ds345,cmd,40); /* read back reply before sending data */

    /* number of bytes = 2 per data point + 2 for checksum */
    ibwrt (ds345,(char *)data,(long)2*number+2);

    sprintf (cmd,"FUNC5\n"); /* arb wf output */

    ibwrt (ds345,cmd,strlen(cmd));
}
```

Estoy interesado especialmente en las líneas:

```
ibwrt (ds345,cmd,strlen(cmd));

ibwrt (ds345,(char *)data,(long)2*number+2);
```

Comment: ¿El problema está en [tag:c] o en [tag:python]? Dices que quieres entender... ¿exactamente que quieres de la comunidad? No esta claro.

Comment: @toledano pinta a que el código lo ha cogido de Internet y como no lo entiende no puede adaptarlo a sus necesidades. ¿cierto?

Comment: Exacto. Creo que quiere traducir el código de C a Python.

Comment: El código lo he tomado del manual del generador de funciones, el problema es que usa LabView, Yo lo que estoy realizando es algo similar en Python y sin usar LabView. El problema que tengo es que no sé que es lo que envía en el código. Especialmente aquí, no entiendo esta parte: 
(ds345,(char *)data,(long)2*number+2);

Comment: @RaymundoTorres Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Gracias, mejoraré la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Por sus nombres, `ibrd( )` tiene toda la pinta de ser la función de lectura *síncrona*, mientras que `ibwrt( )` será la complementaria de escritura.

```
ibwrt( ds345, cmd, strlen( cmd ) );
```

Envia una orden al dispositivo. Su prototipo, según deducimos del código, es

```
ibwrt( int, char *, size_t )
```

siendo el primer argumento el identificador de dispositivo abierto con anterioridad, el segundo una cadena de bytes con los comandos a interpretar por el dispositivo, y el tercero la longitud de dicha cadena, en bytes.

En este primer caso, hace **casi exactamente** lo que tú sugieres: envía la cadena

> `LDWF?0,`

seguida de un número, que indicará el número de puntos.

El segundo caso

```
ibwrt( ds345, (char *)data, (long)( 2 * number + 2 ) );
```

Envía una secuencia de datos, concretamente de enteros. Debido a la operación que realiza, multiplicarlo por 2, podemos estar bastante seguros de que el dispositivo trabaja con datos de 16 *bits* ( 2 *bytes* ).

Además, anexados a esos datos se envía un datos adicional, de 16 *bits*, con un código de comprobación, para detectar posibles errores en el envío. Es decir, si queremos enviar 100 puntos, el tamaño total será:

> `100 * 2 + 2 ==> 202`

Ten presente que en la primera llamada, al enviar la cadena `LDWF?0,`, **no se indican esos bytes de comprobación**. Si queremos enviar 100 puntos, en esa cadena pasaríamos `100` como número, para luego enviar en realidad `202` bytes.

**EDIT**

1 fallo y 1 omisión en lo anterior:

El fallo: al enviar la cadena `LDWF?0,` después del número de puntos, se ha de enviar también un código *retorno de línea* ( un *byte* con el valor 10, `'\n'` en C ). La secuencia completa sería

> `LDWF?0,` + `NÚMERO` + `\n`

La omisión: al enviar los datos, se han de enviar *bytes crudos*, **no** los caracteres de los números. No sabemos el *endian* del dispositivo (el orden de los bytes), así que tendremos que probar con uno u otro, hasta acertar.

Para enviar un valor de 10, **no es** la cadena `"10"` (formada por 2 *bytes*, `49` `48`), sino los bytes `00 10` en *BIG ENDIAN*, o `10` `00` en *LITTLE ENDIAN*.

Los mismo es aplicable para la suma de comprobación. Se realiza sobre los *bytes* crudos, y se envía igualmente como *bytes*.

Comment: Excelente, el Generador de Funciones trabaja con 16 bits.
Esto es parte de lo que estoy realizando en Pyhton:

`inst.write('LDWF?0,3') # Código para enviar 3 Puntos
inst.write('10')
inst.write('10')
inst.write('10')
inst.write('8')#Y al final debería de enviar el checksum(suma de verificación) pero me manda Error el Generadior de funciones`

Comment: @RaymundoTorres Respuesta actualizada. Tuve un par de errores. No se `python`, así que no te puedo orientar sobre la *transformación* :-(